# Messages appears with delayed in /var/log/messages

Tags: rsyslog

I'm using `rsyslog` to collect logs from multiple servers which are all being sent to a single server.
I've noticed that logs sometime appears with delay of 2-5 minutes in `/var/log/messages` of the destination server.

By using `tcpdump` on both source and destination servers, i saw that the messages are being sent from the source server and being received in destination server almost immediately. However, The messages appears with delay in `/var/log/messages` of the destination server, and not at the same moment as they received in the server according to `tcpdump`.

What could be the issue? Please advise.

Here is my rsyslog.conf file:

```
# rsyslog configuration file

# For more information see /usr/share/doc/rsyslog-*/rsyslog_conf.html
# If you experience problems, see http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/troubleshoot.html

#### MODULES ####

# The imjournal module bellow is now used as a message source instead of imuxsock.
$ModLoad imuxsock # provides support for local system logging (e.g. via logger command)
$ModLoad imjournal # provides access to the systemd journal
#$ModLoad imklog # reads kernel messages (the same are read from journald)
#$ModLoad immark  # provides --MARK-- message capability

# Provides UDP syslog reception
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerRun 514

# Provides TCP syslog reception
$ModLoad imtcp
$InputTCPServerRun 514


#### GLOBAL DIRECTIVES ####

# Where to place auxiliary files
$WorkDirectory /var/lib/rsyslog

# Use default timestamp format
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat

# File syncing capability is disabled by default. This feature is usually not required,
# not useful and an extreme performance hit
#$ActionFileEnableSync on

# Include all config files in /etc/rsyslog.d/
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf

# Turn off message reception via local log socket;
# local messages are retrieved through imjournal now.
$OmitLocalLogging on

# File to store the position in the journal
$IMJournalStateFile imjournal.state

$DefaultNetstreamDriver gtls
$DefaultNetstreamDriverCAFile /etc/rsyslog.d/ca.pem
$DefaultNetstreamDriverCertFile /etc/rsyslog.d/cert.pem
$DefaultNetstreamDriverKeyFile /etc/rsyslog.d/key.pem
$ActionSendStreamDriverAuthMode x509/name
$ActionSendStreamDriverPermittedPeer *.aaa.com
#$ActionSendStreamDriverPermittedPeer *.ntwx-unet.ocn.ne.jp
$ActionSendStreamDriverMode 1 # run driver in TLS-only mode
$ActionSendTCPRebindInterval 1 # run driver in TLS-only mode
$ActionSendResendLastMsgOnReconnect     on

#### RULES ####

# Log anything (except mail) of level info or higher.
# Don't log private authentication messages!
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none                /var/log/messages

# The authpriv file has restricted access.
authpriv.*                                              /var/log/secure

# Log all the mail messages in one place.
mail.*                                                  -/var/log/maillog


# Log cron stuff
cron.*                                                  /var/log/cron

# Everybody gets emergency messages
*.emerg                                                 :omusrmsg:*

# Save news errors of level crit and higher in a special file.
uucp,news.crit                                          /var/log/spooler

# Save boot messages also to boot.log
local7.*                                                /var/log/boot.log


# An on-disk queue is created for this action. If the remote host is
# down, messages are spooled to disk and sent when it is up again.
$ActionQueueFileName fwdRule1 # unique name prefix for spool files
$ActionQueueMaxDiskSpace 1g   # 1gb space limit (use as much as possible)
$ActionQueueSaveOnShutdown on # save messages to disk on shutdown
$ActionQueueType LinkedList   # run asynchronously
$ActionResumeRetryCount -1    # infinite retries if host is down
#
$template test,"%HOSTNAME%_Forwading_%timereported%,%msg%\n"
local0.* /opt/aaa/logs/syslog.log
local2.* /opt/aaa/logs/userAuditSyslog.log
```

Comment: Possibly flushing is disabled, `flushOnTXEnd="off"`.

Comment: I have added my conf file

Comment: In the legacy syntax you have, prefix a filename by `-` to have each line flushed to the file immediately, as you already have for `-/var/log/maillog`.

Comment: @meuh I've changed the conf file as you suggested and restarted the service. There is no change at all.